# Updating values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created nested dictionary as below with empty values to updated them later.

```
categ_list = ['cat_a','cat_b']
sub_ = {'sub_1': '', 'sub_2': ''}
m_dict = dict.fromkeys(categ_list, sub_)
```

On updating values using thin loop iterating over the higher level

```
i =0
for cat_ in categ_list:
    i +=1
    m_dict[cat_]['sub_1'] = 'hi ' + cat_
    m_dict[cat_]['sub_2'] = i
```

On printing, I found that it's not updated as I was expecting so I got

```
{'cat_a': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_b', 'sub_2': 2}, 'cat_b': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_b', 'sub_2': 2}}
```

While I was expecting

```
{'cat_a': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_a', 'sub_2': 1}, 'cat_b': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_b', 'sub_2': 2}}
```

Where's issue & how to fix?

Comment: print `id(m_dict['cat_a']), id(m_dict['cat_b'])`. both are same.

Comment: @Epsi95 I need to update the values not to print them.

Comment: I mean to say `m_dict['cat_a']` and `m_dict['cat_b']` pointing to same variable. So you are effectively changing the same dictionary `sub_ = {'sub_1': '', 'sub_2': ''}` in the for loop, not 2

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) states, it puts the value, here `sub_` to each key, each key point to the same and unique dict, so the second loop iteration overwrite the first

> All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object

---

To build it properly, use a `dict-comprehension` and copy the `sub_` dict

```
categ_list = ['cat_a', 'cat_b']
sub_ = {'sub_1': '', 'sub_2': ''}
m_dict = {k: sub_.copy() for k in categ_list}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Issue is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the value is effectively `copy`. So you need to make different variables. One hacky way is to use `json` module

```py
import json

categ_list = ['cat_a','cat_b']
sub_ = {'sub_1': '', 'sub_2': ''}
m_dict = dict.fromkeys(categ_list, sub_)

# here is the hack
m_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(m_dict))

i =0
for cat_ in categ_list:
    i +=1
    m_dict[cat_]['sub_1'] = 'hi ' + cat_
    m_dict[cat_]['sub_2'] = i

print(m_dict)
```

```
{'cat_a': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_a', 'sub_2': 1}, 'cat_b': {'sub_1': 'hi cat_b', 'sub_2': 2}}
```

NOTE: Preferred way is the answer by azro.